# Python if statement invalid syntax

Tags: python

Here's a function I'm writing:

```
def addError(test,range_min,range_max,result):
    err = abs(log(range_max/max(range_min,epsylon))
    if test >= range_min and test <= range_max:
        result.append(err)
    else:
        e1=abs(log(test/max(range_min,epsylon)))
        e2=abs(log(test/max(range_max,epsylon)))
        result.append( min(e1,e2) / max(err,epsylon) *100 + err)
```

When I try to run this, it fails with error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-26-8b4b5ae453e4>", line 12
    if (test >= range_min and test <= range_max):
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why am I getting this?

Comment: BTW easier and more readable: `range_min <= test <= range_max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close all the brackets in the previous line, this should fix the problem:

```
err = abs(log(range_max/max(range_min,epsylon)))
```